# How to calculate the Voltage on the scheme with inverted amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, inverting-amplifier

Given input `1mA` and resistances: `1kOmh` and `100Ohm`. Find the V[exit].

My try:

1. V[on R1] = I[R1]*R1 = 1V
2. As long as R2 "grounded" the I=0A and U=0V
3. The difference in Voltage between "-" and "+" should be 0.

How to solve it?

[image]

Comment: Looks like you already solved it, just be mindful of your signs.

Comment: Why is there resistor connected to the ground? Does it make any difference? To me it does not make any sense...

Comment: It's called a compensation resistor, and is there to null the effects of bias currents. When you're dealing with ideal op amp models, it is unnecessary.

Comment: See also: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/93496/2028

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given V- = V+ = 0V and no current flows into the opamp

Then input current = output current

1mA = (0-Vout)/1000

Therefore Vout = -1V