When should I put a biasing resistor - op-amps
Consider an op amp in the following configuration (the drawing is mine).

How do I know if I should put the biasing resistor \$R_3 = R_1 \parallel R_2\$? I have been told that I should put it to minimize the difference in bias currents between both inputs. But I have also found out that some op-amps are internally compensated, and \$R_3\$ is not advised, for example the OPAx207.
Should I put one if the op-amp I am using is the OPAx827?

You're not minimizing the difference in bias currents.  You're assuming the bias currents are approximately the same, and you're making sure that they pass through similar resistances such that the voltage that the bias currents caused at the input terminals is approximately the same.

related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/45723/7036


Should I put one if the op-amp I am using is the OPAx827?

I start with the input offset voltage as a figure of merit. For the OPAx827 it's 150 μV so, that's an error that cannot be got rid of by "value" design. I use this as a benchmark.
Then I ask myself if the values of R1 and R2 would generate an error of more than one tenth of the input offset voltage (15 μV) when subjected to the maximum bias current: -

The combined parallel resistance of R1 and R2 would need to be 30 kΩ or more at a bias current of 500 pA to create an error of more than 15 μV.
As a final check, I look at the input offset current is. If it's less than the maximum bias current then it's probably worth having R3 if you are relying on the DC accuracy being less than 1 mV.
Of course, you may choose to use a value of bias current that is less than 500 pA. I used it because it was a handy figure when the op-amp is running at 85° C.
But, if your maximum temperature is only (say) 75° C then you can halve the 500 pA bias current to 250 pA. This is based on the approximation that input bias currents roughly double every 10° C for this type of technology.

But I have also found out that some op-amps are internally
compensated, and R3 is not advised, for example the OPAx207.

The word compensation or compensate does not occur in the data sheet. Maybe you mean something else?

cancellation is the word, figure 44! Thank you for your answer

@DarkBulle It seems that the OPAx207 has a rather interesting bias cancellation feature.

You seem to be confusing a few things.
Input bias current, and biasing the op-amp in general, are two different things. Input bias current is current that an op-amp will source or sink to/from its input pins as part of its efforts to establish its own internal DC conditions.
By contrast, any biasing that you do will be external to the op-amp, to establish DC conditions outside. R3 has nothing to do with your own external biasing efforts. Its role is (almost) exclusively to nullify the effects of input bias current, which would otherwise tend to offset the output voltage somewhat.
R3 may have another benefit, which I'll explain in a moment, after I talk about frequency compensation.
An op-amp may or may not have internal frequency compensation. Instability can occur when we use negative feedback, if the op-amp causes phase shifts at certain frequencies which can transform negative feedback into positive. Designers often incorporate circuitry inside the op-amp to take care of this so that we, the users, don't have to.
Compared to the OPA207, the OPA827 has extremely high gain. This makes it rather susceptible to instability under certain conditions, and might require external frequency compensation (in addition to whatever compensation the designers have implemented internally) to mitigate ringing and oscillation. By contrast, the comparatively low-open-loop-gain OPA207, when used in the simple configuration you showed (a basic inverting amplifier), would be stable under almost any conditions.
R3 has nothing to do with frequency compensation.
There are two reasons you would include R3. The first is if input bias current is significant, and would result in unacceptable output offset voltage. The OPA827 has FET inputs, with only picoamps of input bias current. It would not benefit from R3 in this respect. The OPA207 on the other hand claims 2.8nA of input bias current. 2.8nA passing through tens or hundreds of kilohms would develop a significant voltage.
Take for instance the case \$R_1=100k\Omega\$ and \$R_2=500k\Omega\$. The effective resistance of this pair (from the perspective of current into/out of the inverting input) is \$R_1 \parallel R_2 = 83k\Omega\$, through which input bias current must travel. The results in a voltage across it equal to \$2.8nA \times 83k\Omega=230\mu V\$. The closed-loop gain of the circuit would be \$-\frac{R_2}{R_1}=-5\$, which when multiplied by that input offset would result in \$-5 \times 230\mu V=-1.2mV\$ of permanent output offset.
If this is unacceptable to you, in your particular application, then you should include \$R_3=83k\Omega\$ to develop the exact same input offset voltage, so that both inputs have that same offset, cancelling each other out.
The second reason you might want to have a resistance in series with the input is to limit current in/out of that input. In addition to input bias current, it's possible to cause current to flow by applying an input potential outside the op-amp's supply voltage range. For instance, if your op-amp is powered from +5V and 0V, and you apply +7V to one of those inputs, then ESD protecion diodes inside the op-amp will try to clamp the input to +5V. This results in a lot of current flowing, which can damage the device. R3 will limit that current, preventing damage.
If you never apply input potentials beyond the op-amp's own supply potentials, then this isn't a problem, and R3 wouldn't be necessary in that role.
So, do the maths, figure out if your particular combination of input bias current, resistances and gain will result in an unacceptable voltage offset at the output, and if it does, then include R3. It will also help protect the op-amp in case of input over/under voltage, which may or may not be an issue in your particular design.


Should I put one if the op-amp I am using is the OPAx827?

No.
For three reasons...

bias current for this op amp can have positive sign, or negative sign. A bias-compensating resistor R3 can only have a positive resistance.
bias current is so small (+/- 10 pA) that a bias compensation resistor value would have an insignificant effect on any offset...Opamps' voltage offset would very likely dominate for any reasonable-value feedback resistor.
R3 adds noise to op amp output.

Whether you use a bias-compensating resistor or not has little to do with internal compensation. Internal compensation is all about stability at high frequencies.

In simple terms R3 is only really relevant to bipolar type op-amps.
If you are using a JFET input op-amp the input bias is so low that for most purposes it can be ignored.
Even with bipolar types the bias current is low, on a LM324 it is 50nA max, so if the resistance at a pin was 10K the voltage developed would be 0.5mV. The problem is this gets multiplied by the gain of the amplifier.
